# What can I do if I have a Instagram bot login Syntax Error?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instagram

I have a little Syntax Error And I do not understand why. The error is on by the end. I tried  a Instagram bot but it says me that I have a syntax error. I don't know what I need to do. Can you help me?

```
[IG_AUTH]
USERNAME=myusername
PASSWORD=mypassword

[IG_URLS]
LOGIN=https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ 
NAV_USER=https://www.instagram.com/{}/
SEARCH_TAGS=https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/{}/

[ENVIRONMENT]
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH=./chromedriver.exe

; '{}' instances in [IG_URLS] is formatted by a Python method at runtime
```

This was my code.

```
line 170
    LOGIN=https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is the error

Can you please help me.

Comment: Missing single- or double-quotes when assigning strings `LOGIN=https...` -> `LOGIN="https..."`

Comment: Assuming the error is coming form python, that is

Comment: Thank you. It worked

Comment: I'm voting to close this as typo/can't be reproduced/not useful to future readers, since the issue was just missing quotes.